# Practice scraping

Tags: python, screen-scraping

(python 2.7.4)

I would like to print only what I have called url if it contains the word 'watch' I have conducted some trial and error to no avail. Also I would like to know if it's possible to capture the name of each video (from the html) and assign it to the corresponding video any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

The link im using is 'http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=36'

```
import urllib2
import re

def OPEN_URL(url):
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
link=response.read()
response.close()
return link

link=OPEN_URL('http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=36')
match=re.compile('href="(.+?)"').findall(link)
for url in match:
    url='http://thenewboston.org/'+url
    print url
```

Comment: Hint: `beautifulsoup`

Comment: Hint: [scrapy](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use an html parser like beautiful soup to handle this quite easily.

to check substring membership you can use `in`

`'watch.php' in url`

also beautiful soup or an html parser would allow you to get a more exact parse match

```
<li class="contentList">
  <a href="watch.php?cat=36&amp;number=11">11 - Editing Sequences</a>
</li>
```

Instead of all links it looks like you only want links inside of `contentList`'s? Which can easily be queried using xpath, or beautifulsoup, but could be difficult using regexes?

Comment: Exactly, everything inside of "contentList", so basically the href is assigned the name (using the above eg) 11 - Editing Sequences. Will definitely start on beautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check out [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) which is a great library when it comes to parsing and crawling with python.

With that said, you simply have to expand your regexp so it will capture not only href, but also what is within the . So something in lines of

```
re.compile('href="(.+?)">(.+)</a>').findall(s)
```

Of course this won't work as it will most likely capture way to much, but polish is up to you and [manual for re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may try htql:

```
import htql
for href, tx in htql.query(link, "<a (href like 'watch%')>:href, tx"):
  print(href, tx)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try downloading BeautifulSoup and simple regular expressions.